# Rally Portfolio Tree Grid

Tags: rally

I'm trying to create a Rally Portfolio Tree Grid using the SDK.  However, I can't seem to find a post indicating how.  I see the user story hierarchy example, but I can't get it to work with portfolio items.  Could you point me to an existing example?  Or give an example here?  Thanks.

I'm trying to do this outside of Rally, so based on the example, this is what I'm trying.  However, it isn't working.  Suggestions?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Portfolio Grid Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/sdk.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Rally.onReady(function() {
        Ext.define('CustomApp', {
            extend: 'Rally.app.App',
            componentCls: 'app',
            items:{ html:'<a href="https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/">App SDK 2.0rc3 Docs</a>'},
            launch: function() {
                var treeview = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.TreeStoreBuilder').build({
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'rallyportfoliotree',
                        topLevelModel: 'portfolioitem/theme',
                        topLevelStoreConfig: {
                            fetch: true,
                            context: {
                                workspace: "/workspace/7279590206", // use valid OID
                                project : "/project/9400054800", 
                                projectScopeDown: true
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                });
                this.add(treeview);
            }
        });
        Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
            name: 'Portfolio Grid Example',
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    items:{ html:'<a href="https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/">App SDK 2.0rc3 Docs</a>'},
    launch: function() {
        var treeview = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            items: [{
                xtype: 'rallyportfoliotree',
                topLevelModel: 'portfolioitem/theme',
                topLevelStoreConfig: {
                    fetch: true,
                    context: {
                        workspace: "/workspace/111", // use valid OID
                        project : "/project/222", 
                        projectScopeDown: true
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
        this.add(treeview);
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please review the code I added above and give your suggestion?  I'm trying to do this outside of Rally, but I can't get it to work using your example.  Thanks.

Comment: You may see full source here: https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/pi-tree-example There is App-debug.html and App-external.html and both run outside of Rally.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nick.  By changing the topLevelModel to 'portfolioitem/strategicinitiative' I got it to work.  Here's the final code for anyone else who needs it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PI Tree Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function () {
                Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    items:{ html:'<a href="https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/">App SDK 2.0rc3 Docs</a>'},
    launch: function() {
        var treeview = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            items: [{
                xtype: 'rallyportfoliotree',
                topLevelModel: 'portfolioitem/strategicinitiative',
                topLevelStoreConfig: {
                    fetch: true,
                    context: {
                        workspace: "/workspace/111", // NMDS
                        project : "/project/222", // Company X
                        projectScopeDown: true
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
        this.add(treeview);
    }
});


            Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                name:"PI Tree Example",
                parentRepos:""
            });

        });
    </script>


    <style type="text/css">
        .app {
     /* Add app styles here */
}

    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way, in Confluence of course you need to remove the head, body, and html tags, but also you need to remove the parentRepos:"" line.